# How to destructure nested array inside my product Id page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get the nested array inside the `ProductId` page. I'm getting the following error code:

> cannot find undefined

I know that i'm doing wrong by writing Data.Items.find, but if not like this then How..? I want to know how to get the Data.Items array to get it matched with it's id using match.params. And the same goes to Resources page also, even there i'm unable to get my array matched.

what is the best way to do the destructuring to make it work.. ?

```
   //DATA STRUCTURE
      const Data = [
  {
    Branch: "Electrical",
    id: "AA",
    Items: [
      {
        name: "LIGHT FITTINGS",
        id: "1",
        description: "A wide range of light fittings for your need",
        resources: [
          {
            id: "1a",
            title: "Bulb",
            description:
              "This is for all the latest LED light fittings, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",                  
          },
          {
            id: "2a",
            title: "Tube light",
            description:
              "This is for all the latest LED light fittings, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",                
          },
          {
            id: "3a",
            title: "Tube light 2nd",
            description:
              "This is for all the latest LED light fittings, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "SWITCH & SOCKETS",
        id: "2",
        description: "A wide range of Switches & sockets for your need",
        resources: [
          {
            id: "1b",
            title: "Switch",
            description:
              "This is for all the latest switches, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",
          },
          {
            id: "3b",
            title: "15A Switch + Socket",
            description:
              "This is for all the latest switches, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",
          },
          {
            id: "2b",
            title: "Socket",
            description:
              "This is for all the latest Sockets, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
export default Data;
```

//Product ID page

```
import React from "react";
import Data from "../Data";
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Resource from "./Resource";



export default function ProductId({ match }) {
    let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

 const productItem = Data.Items.find(({ id }) => id === match.params.productId);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>ProductId page</h2>
            <div>{productItem.name}</div>

                <ul>
                {productItem.resources.map((sub) => (
               <li key={sub.id}>
                    <Link to={`${url}/${sub.id}`}>{sub.title}</Link>
               </li>
            ))}
            </ul>

            <Route path={`${path}/:subId`} component={Resource} />

        </div>
     );
     }
```

Comment: The main problem is `Data` is also an array and it does not have `Items` as a property as you expect. Probably you need to loop through `Data` first then inside `Items` to find your `id`.

Comment: Yes.. i want to loop through my Data and find the Items array which is nested. I have written Data.Items so that one can understand that exactly what i'm trying to find. I don't know how to loop.. in a correct way.

Comment: `Data[0].Items` - or remove the first set of square brackets around `Data` to turn it into the object your code expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section the main problem is `Data` is also an array and it does not have `Items` as a property as you expect. Probably you need to loop through `Data` first then inside `Items` to find your `id`.

One solution can be to flatten your array first with [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) then use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as before.

> The `flatMap()` method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a `map()` followed by a `flat()` of depth 1, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

See an example with one element from your array:

```js
const Data = [{ Branch: "Electrical", id: "AA",Items: [{name: "LIGHT FITTINGS",id: "1",description: "A wide range of light fittings for your need",resources: [{id: "1a",title: "Bulb",description:"This is for all the latest LED light fittings, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",},{id:"2a",title: "Tube light",description:"This is for all the latest LED light fittings, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",},{id: "3a",title:"Tube light 2nd",description:"This is for all the latest LED light fittings, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",}]},{name: "SWITCH & SOCKETS",id: "2",description: "A wide range of Switches & sockets for your need",resources: [{id: "1b",title: "Switch",description:"This is for all the latest switches, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",},{id: "3b",title: "15A Switch + Socket",description:"This is for all the latest switches, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",},{id: "2b",title:"Socket",description:"This is for all the latest Sockets, no matter who you are, where you’re from and what you’re up to. Exclusive to ASOS, our universal brand is here for you, and comes in all our fit ranges: ASOS Curve, Tall, Petite and Maternity. Created by us, styled by you.",}]}]}]

const routeId = '1';
const result = Data.flatMap(e => e.Items)
                   .find(({id}) => id === routeId);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes sir.. flatMap() method worked for me.. and it is new to me. Thanks for letting me know about this method. You saved my day. Thank you..!!